# c++ template not see in vs express 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create a new c++ project in Visual Studio 2015, but I don't see the c++ project template in the new project dialog in Visual Studio.

Where is it? How can I add it?

[image]

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are different languages. Please use only the relevant tag. Also, please note that most of us cannot read Korean.

Answer (score 1):

As per the MSDN article: [Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60k1461a.aspx)

> In Visual Studio 2015, Visual C++ is not installed by default. When installing, be sure to choose Custom installation and then choose the C++ components you require. Or, if Visual Studio is already installed, choose File | New | Project | C++ and you will be prompted to install the necessary components.

You can change what components of Visual Studio is installed by running the installer again, or going to Program and Features option in the Windows Control Panel.

If you have installed it already, as your screenshot is in Korean, I cannot tell you where the project template is on your screen, but it usually found in the Other Languages section of the installed templates list. [image]

**Update**: Wild guess, but by matching up your screenshot with mine, I would say you would be looking at the **Recent** templates list instead of the **Installed.**